# Windows Phone Push Notifications Remote URI updates don't work in emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I was testing out push notifications and I noticed that when I send push notifications to my tile, it would update the background image and back background image for local images, but when I specify a remote image it didn't work.

I was doing this in the emulator.  I can still manually change the image to a remote via a code change (in the C# code, manually setting the image URI to a remote one), but with push notifications, it doesn't seem to update the image if I specified a remote URI, only a local one.

Is this a defect in the emulator?

Comment: Could you show some code? I am not trying to be one of those people who will not help you if you don't post any code, but it has been a while since I have worked with Silverlight. I am pretty sure I ran into this same issue and it is an easy work-around, but if you could share some code this should help jog my memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few caveats related to remote images: [Tiles Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

- Because of network variability and performance reasons, consider using local resources for Tile images.
- https is not supported for remote images.
- Remote images are limited to 80 KB or less or they will not be
  downloaded.
- Remote images must download in 30 seconds or less or they will not be
  downloaded.
- If the BackGround or BackBackGround images fail to load for any
  reason, none of the other properties set in the update will be
  changed either.

Comment: Right I'm aware of all that, but, still, when I'm testing my application using the windows phone emulator (7.1), the push notification specifying a remote URI doesn't update the tile to a remote URI.  When I try to change the property of the standard tile via code, with the same exact remote URI, it works.  Also, updating other properties (even the same image property) with local URI's seem to work.  So I'm wondering if it is a fault of the emulator.

Comment: And the image isn't over https, and it's less than 80KB? (I'd have to imagine it takes less than 30secs to download)

Answer (score 0):

You should specify allowed domains for push notification images when calling

[HttpNotificationChannel.BindToShellTile Method (Collection)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff708021%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

for example,

```
NotificationChannel.BindToShellTile (new Collection<Uri> { new Uri("http://domain1.com"), new Uri("http://domain2.com") });
```